When "of" is used as "among," do we use "anyone" and "everyone" with it?

"He has the biggest house of anyone here."
"He has the biggest house of everyone here."
He has the biggest house of all the people here."

Do we use "of" with "anyone"/"everyone" in such contexts? Can we say,

"He's the strongest of anyone/everyone here,"   or
"He's the strongest of all the people here."


It's the same as the general case of "everyone" vs "anyone" (either is OK, and "all the people" will work as well, much the same as "everyone"): see this and this for the minor difference in meaning.

Short answer-in-comment: YES.

You can say:

He's stronger than anyone here.

but not

He is the strongest of anyone here.

That construction requires a partitive:

He's the strongest of the crew.

in the sense that he is being selected out from the crew by virtue of his status as strongest.
A comparison with anyone is grammatical but the partitive "of anyone"  is ungrammatical because anyone is not a group noun and is singular:

Does anyone here recognize this hat?
*Do anyone here  recognize this hat?  number-agreement issue

of anyone is a possessive:

Is this the hat of anyone here?

Consider these, some of which might be considered marginal or worse by anyone here :

Is anyone here a doctor?
He is the best doctor of anyone here.
Someone is without their gloves. Their hands must be the coldest of anyone here.
Does this hat belong to anyone here?
This hat is the nicest of anyone here.


"He is the strongest of anyone here" sounds perfectly grammatical and idiomatic to me. I don't see the distinction between "the crew" and "anyone here".

@DanielRoseman Do you understand  "anyone here" to refer to a group? What if I said "Hand this message to anyone here."?

Er, yes. It refers to the group of people that are present. If you told me that, I would pick a person at random out of those that are here.

@DanielRoseman  But it is possible to hand a message to a group?  Doesn't it mean to any one selected at random from a room of people?  I don't know what "er" means, by the way. Is that "I suppose" or is it meant to have a snarky tone?

You can hand it to any member of a group, yes. Again though the same argument could be made about your alternative, "the crew".

And it means "I'm confused as to why you would ask."

The same argument can't be made with "the crew".   As I said, that is a partitive construction.   A subset of one, the strongest.  The strongest of the crew.  Whereas the strongest of anyone?  The strongest of any individual here?  That's why I'm asking whether you understand it to refer to a group.

Interesting. He is the strongest of anyone here sounds natural to me and means He is the strongest person in the room. Whereas, following your other example, I would say Hand this message to someone here, if a random selection of one person was intended. I need to think about this some more.

@PeterKirkpatrick  You would find "Hand this message to anyone here"  marginal in some way? How about "Hand this message to anyone there"?

I'm thinking that context matters (as always!). The advance group of soldiers discovers critical intel about enemy movements, and the sergeant says to the radio operator, Contact Headquarters. Hand this message to anyone there. So I certainly see that these expressions can be right. But I'm not sure if they always will be.
